# Why is my programme stuck in the if loop?

Tags: visual-c++

I am new to C++ and this is like my first program I made and I used Visual C++ 2010 Express. 
It is a weight conversion thing. There is an if loop, an else if loop and an else.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
float ay,bee;
char char1;
cout << "Welcome to the Ounce To Gram Converter" << endl << "Would you like to convert [O]unces To Grams or [G]rams To Ounces?" << endl;
start:
cin >> char1;

if (char1 = "G" ||"g"){
cout << "How many grams would you like to convert?" << endl;
cin >> bee;
cout << bee << " grams is equal to: " << bee*0.035274 << " ounces." << endl; goto start;
}

else if (char1 = "o"||"O"){ 
cout << "How many ounces would you like to convert" << endl;
cin >> ay;
cout << ay << " ounces is equal to: " << ay/0.035274 << " grams." << endl; goto start;
}   

else{
    cout << "Error 365457 The character you entered is to retarded to comprehend" << endl;
goto start;
}

cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
    }
```

If I enter a "g", it executes this:

```
    if (char1 = "G" ||"g"){
cout << "How many grams would you like to convert?" << endl;
cin >> bee;
cout << bee << " grams is equal to: " << bee*0.035274 << " ounces." << endl; goto start;
}
```

like it should

However, if I enter an "o", it executes this:

```
    if (char1 = "G" ||"g"){
cout << "How many grams would you like to convert?" << endl;
cin >> bee;
cout << bee << " grams is equal to: " << bee*0.035274 << " ounces." << endl; goto start;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
    else if (char1 = "o"||"O"){ 
cout << "How many ounces would you like to convert" << endl;
cin >> ay;
cout << ay << " ounces is equal to: " << ay/0.035274 << " grams." << endl; goto start;
}
```

Even if I put something random, like "h" 
This Happens:

```
    if (char1 = "G" ||"g"){
cout << "How many grams would you like to convert?" << endl;
cin >> bee;
cout << bee << " grams is equal to: " << bee*0.035274 << " ounces." << endl; goto start;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
    else{
    cout << "Error 365457 The character you entered is to retarded to comprehend" << endl;
goto start;
}
```

Please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using `goto`? You should really consider using an actual loop (`for` or `while`).

Answer (score 3):

`char1 = "o"||"O"` will always evaluate to true, because `"O"` is not null.

You want to use `char1 == 'o' || char == 'O'` and similar all over your if statements.

Note that `=` is assignment and `==` is an equality check. Use `==` when testing for equality and `=` when assigning. C and C++ allows you to use `=` in a check which returns the value of the assignment. This value is not 0, which evaluates to true and thus your if statement executes.

Comment: I did  change it to        char1==o||char1 == O,       and alike forr all of them, but i am getting errors under the equals signs. it says operand types incompatible ("char" and const char*)

Comment: Use single quotes not double quotes